# Is it possible to stop inheriting CSS within shadowDom from HTML tag?

Tags: javascript, html, css, web-component, shadow-dom

Im injecting some Javascript that creates an isolated div located at the top of the body. Within this div there is a shadowDom element. The reason I went with shadowDom is because I thought it stoped CSS from bleeding in to all the divs within the shadowDom. But I can clearly see that it is inheriting style from the  tag(font-size: 62.5%;). This is causing my text to be smaller. I can override this with adding font-size: 100% !Important but even though it crosses it out in the inspector tools it does not actually change. The only way I can get it to work is by unchecking the box in the CSS portion.

Please Help

Thanks,

Dev Joe

[HTML Shadow Dom IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4xdOb.png)

[CSS Checked IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gjdh.png)

[CSS Unchecked IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jFiI0.png)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should not use a relative font size (like `100%`) because it applies to inherited size... so this will have no effect.

Insead, you should define a rule to the `:host` CSS peudo-class:

```
:host {
   font-size: initial ;
}
```

NB: You'll need to add `!important` only if the `font-size` defined in the container (the main document) applies to the host element directly.

NB #2: You can use `all: initial` instead but you cannot combine it with `!important`.

```js
host.attachShadow( { mode: 'open' } )
    .innerHTML = `
      <style>
        :host { all: initial }
      </style>
      Inside Shadow Root <br>
      <div>Div in Shadow DOM</div>
      <slot></slot>
    `
```

```css
body { font-size : 62.5% ; color: red }
```

```html
Small Font
<div>Div in main Document</div>
<div id=host>Light DOM</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

No need for shadow dom, just use the all attribute to disable the inheritance.

```
#myElement {
  all: initial;
}
```

Comment: This does not work as it breaks everything I just want that specific thing to be gone

Comment: ShadowDom is definitely still useful if you dont want other styles to bleed into it - any nested styles are not applied and reset by default. They are also not influenced by `!important` rules outside the element, etc...